# How can we call rest api using ssl certificate in azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have been trying to configure/call a rest full api through azure data factory where it gives response in xml format.

1. Using REST Linked Service: it doesn't have the certificate authentication type. So cannot go with this.
2. Using HTTP Linked Service: it has the certificate authentication and able to create it successfully but when try to create a dataset it doesn't have the xml format to choose.
   I have even read the supported file formats in azure data factory and mentioned the same.

Is there any other posbilities where im missing in azure data factory.
Could anyone help on this please.

Else i will go with Azure Logic app or Azure Databricks.
Still i need to know how can we configure in above two referred azure resources but i will try it later on.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML format is supported for the following connectors: Amazon S3, Azure Blob, Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1, Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2, Azure File Storage, File System, FTP, Google Cloud Storage, HDFS, HTTP, and SFTP. It is supported as source but not sink.

Ref: [XML format in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-xml)

When we create dataset in Web active, we can choose the XML format:

For example, click New-->Blog Storage-->XML:
[image]

Please check if your source supports the XML format file.